# Is it possible to use non global provider as resolver for child route in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have defined route as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [ 
      {
        path: "view/:id",
        component: DetailComponent,
        resolve: {
          details: (
            route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          ) => {
            return inject(ParentComponentService).resolve(route.params['id'])
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and ParentComponent is annotated as follows

```
@Component({
  ....
  providers: [
    ParentComponentService
  ]
})
export class TrafficDashboardComponent
```

this fails misereably with `No provider for ParentComponentService` when accessing `/parent/view/5`

Is it possible to use "component scoped provider" as route resolver? The purpose.

The reason why I am using scoped service is that I want to be able to preset selected details as it is available for ParentComponent as well as to be able to directly navigate to the child route.
Also I dont have to bother about clrearing the service in such configuration as it is done for me by angular when leaving details component.

Comment: You should Define the ParentComponentService as a route resolver in your routes array.
```
    component: ParentComponent,


    providers: [ ParentComponentService ],
```

Comment: If you’re on angular 16 there’s route inputs available,  `withComponentInputBinding()` added to `provideRouter()`

Comment: @callback It "works" but it looks like that service is of global scope now, which I don't want (onDestroy is not called even when navigating to a different feature module)

Comment: looks like this is "intended" https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095

Comment: Do you have ParentComponentService as a provider in your ParentComponent? if so you should remove it

Comment: This is what I have understood - remove it from component level, and add it to the route config. And then, lifecycle is gone as described  github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095. So in general, your answer is more than fine, but due to that issue, it will not be viable and I will probably stick to component level service with direct call invocation on child side, bypassing router in the process.